# schema design for ecommerce product

Tags: python, django, django-models, database-design

I am exploring models in django where I am trying to create a model for e-commerce product. The schema that I have designed is follow for now

```
from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=80)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Product(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  total_stock = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Attribute(models.Model):
  '''
    attribute can be like color, material, size and many more
  '''
  name = models.CharField(max_length=80)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class AttributeValue(models.Model):
  '''
    Values for the selected attribute like for size attr
    the values can be Large, Medium, Small and etc
  '''
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  attribute = models.ForeignKey(Attribute, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)
  discount = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)
  stock = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class ProductAttribute(models.Model):
  '''
    Associate Particular attribute to Particular product
  '''
  product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  attribute = models.ForeignKey(Attribute, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.product.name


class ProductImage(models.Model):
  product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'pic_folder/')

  def __str__(self):
    return self.product.name
```

My question is when I researched for scalable e-commerce product design (scalable in terms of better table relation and covering most of the factors in e-commerce), I saw various tables like 
`ProductVariant`, `ProductVariantImage`, `ProductOptions` and etc. So I got confused on those terminology. Can anyone help me to make me understand that with example and how can i adjust those table in my `models.py`?

Here is the link

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HCqo.png

Comment: Can you share the link that you are talking about?

Comment: I have shared the image link @CalebGoodman.

Comment: Where did that image come from?  I thought you were talking about an article explaining ecommerce DB design.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want to understand the terms and how they relate to each other, correct? And once you understand, you can decide how to adjust the schema & models.

**ProductVariant**: A "version" of the Product. From an e-commerce point of view, this can mean something that doesn't neatly fit into the **Attribute** or **AttributeValue** models. For example, a product can have a variant:

- size
- country of origin
- language
- men only, women only, unisex
- different price point (high-end vs. low-end, public vs. private)

I think you can do without a **ProductVariant** model, and just get things to work using attributes. It may be meaningful to use **ProductVariant** as a reference to a pre-existing **Product** (foreign key constraint on Product.id). See [here](https://www.datafeedwatch.com/resources/academy/product-variants) and [here](https://ithemes.com/ecommerce-product-variants-101/).

**ProductVariantImage**: A version of the **ProductImage**.

**ProductOptions**: The options for the Product. You can just use **Attributes** instead. This table/model doesn't seem to be any different than what **Attributes** & **AttributeValues** already have.

Comment: you are saying a product can have variant on size. Is not the size factor comes into attribute? Sorry if i misunderstood. Can you provide an example by taking a basis on clothing product, please?

Comment: Sure. You're right about size being stored as an attribute. That's probably how I would first design my model. However, it can also be defined as a product variant. A product variant simply means another way your product can be presented to the customer. Sizes are a typical product variant because the same product can be sold in many different sizes. See the example they provide at https://ithemes.com/ecommerce-product-variants-101/.